# Program for Sequential Monte Carlo Algorithm

Tags: monte-carlo, software

Does anybody has the
example of the program which
simulates Sequential Monte Carlo Algorithm?
In any software. I'm trying to write such
kind of program but there constantly are
question and problems I can't solve.
Regards

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to do with the algorithm? A Monte Carlo algorithm can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: SMC is also known as a Particle Filter, I believe.

Comment: Here are two R packages.  I don't know a great deal about Sequential Monte Carlo, but these are the vignettes for the packages with all of the functions explained. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SMC/SMC.pdf  and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppSMC/RcppSMC.pdf

Comment: I meant any example of ABC SMC use for posterior distribution determination. For example, X|θ ∼ Binomial(n, θ), θ∼ Beta(1, 1), n=47. I want to estimate posterior distribution θ|X without calculating full conditionals (like for Gibbs sampling).

Comment: You want to try using SMC for that model in particular, @oleg? You realize there's a simple analytic solution for the posterior in that model though, right?

Comment: Yep, I know. I just want to understand how to apply ABC SMC to any simple hierarchical model since then I'll need to apply it to complex model with many variables. In intermediate distribution construction as well as perturbation kernel selection I see some problems. Therefore I thought that watching any program code which implement the algorithm SMC will help me to understand how it really works.

Answer (score 0):

One such library for Python is [Qinfer](http://qinfer.org/). It's target audience is the field of quantum information processing. However, aside from the usage examples and a few of the built in models and distributions, it is completely general.

Below is the simple conjugate model you mentioned in the comments, which should work in a jupyter notebook. We do a single update specifying that 70 out of 100 flips are heads.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import qinfer as qi
import numpy as np

model = qi.BinomialModel(qi.CoinModel())
prior = qi.BetaDistribution(alpha=1, beta=1)
smc = qi.SMCUpdater(model, 10000, prior)

N = 100
d = N-70

# these experimental parameters seem cumbersome for simple models
eps = np.array([N]).astype(model.expparams_dtype)

# perform update step:
smc.update(d, eps)
smc.plot_posterior_marginal(range_min=0, range_max=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a particle filter implemented in Matlab for estimating the state of Gaussian Switching Linear Dynamic System (SLDS):
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62959-particle-filter

The sequential monte carlo algorithm is described in Nando de Freitas paper titled: Rao-Blackwellized particle filtering for fault diagnosis.